# When running from Laravel scheduler: Could not start chrome /system.slice/cron.service is not a snap cgroup

Tags: laravel, selenium-chromedriver, scheduler, laravel-10, symfony-panther

I created a job that automates certain processes on a web site that was lacking an API using the `symfony/panther` package in Laravel.

When I manually run the command from the command line, it always works as expected.

When I run it thru the scheduler, it always fails:

```
$schedule->command('reports:get-latest')->dailyAt('02:00')->withoutOverlapping();
```

This is the error it fails with:

> Could not start chrome. Exit code: 1 (General error). Error output: /system.slice/cron.service is not a snap cgroup

I've searched for this error, but have found nothing specific related to this scenario that might cause it to fail only when run by the Laravel scheduler.

I installed the Chrome driver both using `composer require --dev dbrekelmans/bdi` and `apt-get install chromium-chromedriver` on the AWS Ubuntu instance I'm running it on.

Comment: [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-launch-snap-applications-with-cgroup-v2/27700/10) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1951491) might be relevant (maybe)

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't derive a solution from those resources.

Comment: If you installed chrome with a snap you can try installing chromium directly from a repository and use that instead.

Comment: I installed it using the command `apt-get install chromium-chromedriver` and I also installed a project local copy using `composer require dbrekelmans/bdi`

Comment: Not the chrome driver but the chrome browser itself

Comment: I didn't install the Chrome browser. This is entirely console command based using the Symfony Panther package.

Comment: The chrome driver is remote-control software that can control a chrome or chromium browser (probably running in headless mode). You need to have one installed.

Comment: Strangely the Panther docs don't mention that as a requirement and I don't have any need to install a headless copy of the Chrome browser when I run it manually from the commandline. The only problem arises when the cron tries to run it, then I get this error. That is what I am trying to figure out...what is the difference here? For clarity, this is a simple AWS EC2 with Ubuntu installed.

Comment: If you have not installed any sort of chrome binary then it's possible panther installs its own chrome or chromium dependency to work. That means it's possible that it can only be ran by the user who installed panther initially. If you set up the cron task via `/etc/crontab` try removing it from there and set it up via the command `crontab -e` instead to have it run as the current user rather than root

Comment: Reinstalling the driver the --dev flag resolved the issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reinstalling the driver with --dev flag since you mention in your post that you used `composer require --dev dbrekelmans/bdi`?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant I did `sudo snap install chromium --devmode` which fixed the problem.